# StorageFile - gaining access to image outside LocalStorage

Tags: windows-runtime

Is it possible in WinRT to gain access to image file outside LocalStorage such that I could use file URI to bind it to source property in Image control? I can't use .OpenRead() with storing files in memory because I could have too many images (possible OutOfMemoryException). I also can't control my container rendering behaviour - it's FlipView and it doesn't have anything like ContainerContentChanging event in GridView (as far as I know).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless your image files are in the pictures library and your app declares the "Pictures Library" capability in its manifest - you will need to ask the user for permission to access these files by using a file or folder picker. You can then save the token that allows access to that file/folder in the future access list.

One [article](http://www.jonathanantoine.com/2012/08/06/keep-access-to-filesfolders-the-user-granted-you/) I found that describes this gives these quick snippets:

**To save token**

```cs
var picker = new FolderPicker();
picker.FileTypeFilter.Add("*");
var folder = await picker.PickSingleFolderAsync();

StorageApplicationPermissions.FutureAccessList.AddOrReplace(Token, folder);
```

**To access a storage item unlocked by a token**

```cs
var folder = await StorageApplicationPermissions
    .FutureAccessList.GetFolderAsync(Token);

var fileToCopy = await StorageFile
    .GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/Logo.png"));
await fileToCopy.CopyAsync(folder, "Logo.png", NameCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
```

You could possibly use the file/folder path as a token if you need to enable more of these.